# How to use iText in android to write other Languages to pdf?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I'm developing an android App,I wanna export a pdf from my App that contains some simple text data in it.So I used iText library in my App.I could export a pdf with some English text finally,but I want to write other languages to pdf like Persian. I read the docs about writing  other languages in iText but I could not implement it in my App. how can I do this? and this is my code:

```
        Button pdf = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.pdf);
        pdf.setOnClickListener(this);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.pdf:

        try {
            File newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TestFolder1");

            if (!newFolder.exists()) {
                newFolder.mkdir();
            }
            try {
                file = new File(newFolder, "MyTest" + ".pdf");
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("ex: " + ex);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("e: " + e);
        }
        try {

              Document document = new Document();
              PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
              document.open();
              fp.addMetaData(document);
              fp.addTitlePage(document);
              fp.addContent(document);
              document.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

        break;
                }
             }
```

and,

```
    public class FirstPdf {
  private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18,
      Font.BOLD);
  private static Font subFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16,
      Font.BOLD);
  private static Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
      Font.BOLD);
  BaseFont tahoma;
  Font myfont;

public FirstPdf(){

  }

  // iText allows to add metadata to the PDF which can be viewed in your Adobe
  // Reader
  // under File -> Properties
  public void addMetaData(Document document) {
    document.addTitle("My PDF Export");
    document.addSubject("Using Daryan Co Application");
    document.addKeywords("Java, PDF, iText");
    document.addAuthor("Darian Co");
    document.addCreator("Simple User1");
  }

  public void addTitlePage(Document document)
      throws DocumentException {
    Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
    // We add one empty line
    addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
    // Lets write a big header
    preface.add(new Paragraph(b, myfont));
    addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
    // Will create: Report generated by: _name, _date
    preface.add(new Paragraph("Report generated by: " + "User1" + ", " + new Date(), //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
        smallBold));
    addEmptyLine(preface, 3);
    //preface.add(new Paragraph("This document describes something which is very important ",
    //   smallBold));

   // addEmptyLine(preface, 8);

    //preface.add(new Paragraph("This document is a preliminary version and not         subject to your license agreement or any other agreement with vogella.com ;-).",
    //    redFont));

    document.add(preface);
    // Start a new page
    //document.newPage();
  }

  public void addContent(Document document) throws DocumentException {
    Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Application Output", catFont);
    anchor.setName("Application Output");

    // Second parameter is the number of the chapter
    Chapter catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);

    Paragraph subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory 1", subFont);
    Section subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
    // add a list
    //createList(subCatPart);
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    addEmptyLine(paragraph, 5);
    subCatPart.add(paragraph);

    // add a table
    createTable(subCatPart);

    // now add all this to the document
    document.add(catPart);
  }

  private static void createTable(Section subCatPart)
      throws BadElementException {
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Parameter"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Value"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);
    table.setHeaderRows(1);
    table.addCell("City: ");
    table.addCell(""+ Data.p1city);
    table.addCell("A: " );
    table.addCell(""+ Data.p1result);
    table.addCell("Hight: ");
    table.addCell(""+ Data.p2h);
    table.addCell("Structure Type: ");
    table.addCell(""+Data.p2structureType);
    table.addCell("T: ");
    table.addCell("" + Data.p2period);
    table.addCell("B: ");
    table.addCell(""+ Data.p3b);
    subCatPart.add(table);

  }

    private static void createList(Section subCatPart) {
    List list = new List(true, false, 10);
    list.add(new ListItem("First point"));
    list.add(new ListItem("Second point"));
    list.add(new ListItem("Third point"));
    subCatPart.add(list);
  }

  private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
    }
  }

    }
```

Comment: this is my code that write English PDF, and I want to know how to add code to write in Persian to this code.

Comment: You are using the standard Type 1 font Times Roman. That font doesn't know how to display Persian. Please use a different font, more specifically a font that supports Persian glyphs.

Comment: @Bruno Yes,your right,and I know this,also I tried creating other Fonts in English for iText but the question is how can I create Fonts for persian in android??

Comment: Before answering that question, you need to answer this one: do you have a font file that contains Persian glyphs? If not, you can't create a `Font` or `BaseFont` objects for Persian.

Comment: What do you mean? What is font file? are you talking about for example arial.TTf ? @BrunoLowagie

Comment: A font file is a file that contains a font program. Arial.ttf is an example of a font file. It contains descriptions of every glyph that is part of that font. iText needs those description to (1) know the metrics of each glyph, and (2) copy the description into the PDF if you want to embed the font. Having the metrics is a *conditio sine qua non* to create the PDF. Embedding a font is recommended but not mandatory. However: if you don't embed a font in a Persian document, many people won't be able to read the document.